# Как открывать текстовые файлы разных форматов?

Tags: c#, winforms, потоки-данных, text

Как загрузить в RichTextBox файлы разных форматов(rtf,txt,pdf,doc,docx) в c#?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете загрузить txt и rtf при помощи [RichTextBox.LoadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d76176b1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), указав параметр `fileType` как `RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText` или `RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText`.

Для поддержки pdf, doc, docx ищите сторонние библиотеки.

При помощи [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423444/10105) можно перегнать файл из doc/docx-форматов в rtf на лету (но требуется установленный на клиентской машине Microsoft Word).

Для pdf подойдёт, например [`RichTextBox` от Telerik](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/richtextbox/features/import-export/export), но он, разумеется, платный. (Впрочем, это должна быть не ваша забота, а вашего работодателя.)