# Отображение содержимого word файла

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите как в richTextBox отобразить содержимое файлов с расширением doc и docx ? С txt файлами всё нормально, а при открытии doc вылазят кракозябры, типо PK. Задача состоит в том, что есть задание написать программу для ведения своего дневника. Соответственно нужно сделать, чтобы была возможность открывать уже сохранённые записи со всем содержимым:форматированием текста, картинками и тд. Выводить всё это содержимое хочу, соответственно, в richTextBox.

```
 private void открытьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog o = new OpenFileDialog();
            o.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*|*.doc|";
            if (o.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(o.FileName, Encoding.Default);
            }
        }
```

Comment: не забывайте метку WinForms, хоть по вашему коду это видно, но тем не менее.

Comment: Подобный вопрос уже [был](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/408099/docx-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-richtextbox).

Comment: docx файл надо либо открыть вордовой библиотекой либо конвертировать в txt

Comment: не подскажите название библиотеки ?

Comment: по ссылке есть как минимум вариант с использованием interop и самого Word. А для DocX есть родной SDK OpenXML

Comment: Всё, уже открыл. Однако теперь вопрос как отображать из doc все таблицы, картинки и тд.

Comment: если кратко - отобразить вы сможете только то, что поддерживает формат RTF, это уже надо спеки смотреть и примеры для RichTextBox, но не рассчитывайте что сможете сохранить исходное форматирование. RTF например понятия не имеет о выравнивании по ширине и т.д.

Comment: Какой выход из ситуации ?

Comment: смотря для чего это вам нужно, надеюсь что вы не хотите сделать собственный Word  с преферансом и барышнями =)

Comment: Легкого выхода нет. Иначе бы давно уже были бесплатные аналоги Word'а.

Comment: Добавьте более подробное описание вашей задачи в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С учетом уточнения решаемой задачи, могу посоветовать просто работать с родным для RichTextBox RTF-форматом. Примеров создания форматированного текста достаточно и в MSDN, и тут, и в сети в принципе. Word и LibreOffice умеют открывать и сохранять RTF, так что ваши файлы будут открываться не только в вашей программе. Когда сможете реализовать это, можно начать адаптировать под современные форматы документов, если будет время и желание.

Comment: То есть, если я буду сохранять таблицы и картинки в документе RTF формата, то они будут без проблем открываться ?

Comment: @Андрей да. RTF очень старый формат, для него даже встроенный WordPad есть. Хотя не смотря на возраст - формат все еще жив. Иногда он удобнее тяжелых современных форматов разметки, хотя конечно корявости ему не занимать =)

Comment: Ну для начала можно и его использовать. Спасибо большое за помощь. Полдня сижу над этой задачей.

Comment: @Андрей не забывайте отмечать наиболее правильный с вашей точки зрения вопрос зеленой галочкой, это даст возможность другим посетителям быстро понять что именно из предложенного вам помогло. Даже если после появится более правильный или подходящий ответ, ее всегда можно переставить.

Comment: А для того, чтобы корректно сохранить изображение в файл нужны танцы с бубном ? Или обычный код записи в файл ?

Comment: У RTB есть собственные методы сохранения и загрузки файлов, только формат нужно указать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46735/discussion-between--and-rdorn).

Answer (score 3):

Дайте себе труд хотя бы попробовать поискать на английском:
[load word file (.docx) in richtextbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722434/load-word-file-docx-in-richtextbox)

Копирую оттуда код:

```
    if (openFile.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        // Open document 
        string originalfilename = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFile.FileName);

        if (openFile.CheckFileExists && new[] { ".docx", ".doc", ".txt", ".rtf" }.Contains(Path.GetExtension(originalfilename).ToLower()))
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            object File = originalfilename;
            object nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordobject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            wordobject.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document docs = wordObject.Documents.Open(ref File, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
            docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
            docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
            rtfMain.Document.Paste();
            docs.Close(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
            wordobject.Quit(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);


            MessageBox.Show("file loaded");
        }
    }
```

Может быть это и не будет идеальный результат, который вас полностью устроит, но с ним ваш вопрос не будет таким поверхностным.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Мой технический английский плоховат и я не всегда понимаю нашел ли я точно то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Как уже выше писали, необходима конвертация в формат RTF.

DOC - Бинарный формат, с весьма сложной структурой. Библиотеки, не требующие офиса для работы с ним, продают за большие деньги. Есть пара бесплатных. ОДна опенсорс - порт с джавовской либы POI. Вторая Spire DOC, имеет кучу ограничений на количество обрабатываемого текста.

DOCX - Архив с набором XML-файлов. Есть библиотека от майкрософт OpenXML, которая отлично справляется с docx файлами. Но она немного сложновата для освоения и чаще всего используют оболочку над ней - ClosedXML. Обе библиотеки бесплатные и не требуют установленного офиса. Или можно использовать кучу других бесплатных библиотек для работы с docx. Все они легко ставятся через nuget.

COM Interop, описанный выше, идеально подходит, если стоит офис. Он "из коробки" поддерживает все форматы и прекрасно конвертирует.

Если же офис может отсутствовать, то я бы посоветовал использовать или POI или связку POI/OpenXML.

И надо помнить, что RTF сильно отличается от DOC/DOCX, и результат может отличаться от того, что вы видите MS Word. Потому, если цель - просмотр документов, я бы посоветовал конвертацию в HTML.